# Java thread as an event loop thread

Tags: java, multithreading, qthread, event-loop

I want to use a thread as an event loop thread. I mean a Java thread with a "QThread like behaviour" (`t2` in the following example). Explanation:

I have a thread `t1` (main thread) and a thread `t2` (a worker thread). I want that `method()`, called from `t1`, is executed in `t2` thread.

Currently, I made this code (it works, but I don't like it):

-Thread **t1** (Main thread, UI thread for example):

```
//...
// Here, I want to call "method()" in t2's thread
Runnable event = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        t2.method(param);
    }
};
t2.postEvent(event);
//...
```

-Thread **t2**:

```
//...
Queue<Runnable> eventLoopQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Runnable>();
//...
@Override
public void run()
{
    //...
    Runnable currentEvent = null;
    while (!bMustStop) {
        while ((currentEvent = eventLoopQueue.poll()) != null) {
            currentEvent.run();
        }
    }
    //...
}

public void method(Param param)
{
    /* code that should be executed in t2's thread */
}

public void postEvent(Runnable event)
{
    eventLoopQueue.offer(event);
}
```

This solution is ugly. I don't like the "always-working" main loop in `t2`, the new `Runnable` allocation each time in `t1`... My program can call `method` something like 40 times per second, so I need it to be efficient.

I'm looking for a solution that should be used on Android too (I know the class [Looper](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Looper.html) for Android, but it's only for Android, so impossible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using `BlockingQueue` instead of `Queue` for its method `take()` will block the thread until an element is available on the queue, thus not wasting cycles like `poll()` does.

Answer (score 0):

You could as well synchronize (using synchronized / wait / notify) to wait until a new even is posted. But mentioned in the previous answer, the BlockingQueue could do the job. Just do not forget to interrupt when you plan to quit the thread (in both cases).

Answer (score 0):

Since Java 1.5 there is an excellent solution provided out of the box for thread pooling. You have a Thread pool to which you can submit a Task for execution. The pool takes a thread and executes your task. Once the task is executed the Thread transparently returns to the pool. Please look at [ExecutorService](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) interface and all its implementations. Also take a look at [Executors](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html) helper class. This should give you all you need and much more